# Sound glitches using fft segmented convolution

Tags: convolution, infinite-impulse-response, finite-impulse-response, hrtf

I’m trying to build a binaural audio player, I'm using MIT Kemar c library to get the hrtf and a fft segmented convolution. It works on real time but the problem is each time I change the hrtf I hear noises like small cracks or something like vinyl noise. But I'm not sure why. Please help.
If you are interested in the project here is my github repo:
https://github.com/Bk8/Binaural

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to reduce cracking noises between convolutional block filtering parameter changes is to use an overlapping of the blocks and do a cross fading (linear or raised-cosine) of the overlapping segments.

Comment: OP might already be doing Overlap-Add for his/her "fft segmented convolution".

Comment: In that case, the OP might need to complete and end one overlap-add sequence, start another overlap-add sequence using the some previously filtered blocks over again, and cross fade the two overlapped overlap-add sequences at some point a full impulse response length into the new sequence.

Comment: well, unlike Overlap-Save, in which if you suddenly change to another FIR coefficient set you *will* get a jump discontinuity, with OLS changing to a completely different coefficient set will result in some form of crossfading from the old to the new during the overlap-add portion.

Answer (score 0):

Mixing just the overlaps didn't worked at all, I used the method described here:

https://codeandsound.wordpress.com/2015/04/08/implementing-binaural-hrtf-panner-node-with-web-audio-api/

First you filter low frequencies then you render the next segment and mix between the new segment and the old, and finally add the low frecuencies back.